# .NET inline IF ternary operator returns unexpected decimal value

Tags: .net, vb.net, if-statement

**I expect the following to result in the value of `14D` being placed in the variable `D3`.**

However, this is not happening.

```
Dim D1 As Decimal = 14D
Dim D2 As Decimal = Nothing
Dim D3 As Decimal

D3 = If(D2 = Nothing, D1, D2)
```

**The final value of `D3` is `0D`.**

- In the debugger, "0D = nothing" evalutes to true
- In the debugger, "If(D2 = Nothing, D1, D2)" evaluates to 14D
- This is .NET Framework 4.0 in an ASP.NET code-behind file.

**Why does D3 end up with the value of 0D rather than 14D?**

## UPDATE #1

- Please note that in the debugger watch window, D3 shows a value of 0D. However, if I output the value of D3 to the screen, using response.write(D3.ToString()), the value of D3 is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1 (most likely)

Make sure that you are examining the value of D3 in both the debugger AND in the actual application. For example, try this:

```
Response.Write(D3.ToString())
```

Does it output 0 or 14? I bet it outputs 0.

Sometimes the debugger shows false information.

## Option 2

If you compile to x86 instead of x64, it will work just fine. Or, you can use `If D2 = Nothing Then D3 = D1 Else D3 = D2`. In fact, `D3 = If(True, D1, D2)` fails. It fails even if D2 is not assigned nothing. If D2 is assigned 1D, D3 is still assigned 0D. Must be a compiler error.

Answer (score 2):

Decimal is a value type and can't actually be equal to Nothing. Setting a value type to Nothing will result in it taking it's default value (in this case 0D).

Here's a working solution:

```
Dim D1 As Decimal = 14D
Dim D2 As Decimal = Nothing
Dim D3 As Decimal

D3 = If(D2 = CType(Nothing, Decimal), D1, D2)
```

This is much cleaner in C#:

```
decimal d1 = 14m;
decimal d2 = default(decimal);
decimal d3;

d3 = (d2 == default(decimal)) ? d1 : d2;
```

Comment: The "working solution" does not work -- it assigns zero to D3.

Comment: Weird. I'm using VS2008 -- but I think OP is using something newer.

Answer (score 0):

`Decimal`, just like other numeric value types (not reference types, like objects/classes are) default to 0.  They cannot have `Nothing` assigned to them, as value types exist once declared.

If you want to set a value type to nothing, you must declare it as `Nullable` in one of the following ways:

```
Dim d1 As Nullable(Of Decimal) = Nothing
```

Or

```
Dim d2 As Decimal? = Nothing
```

The question mark is short-hand for the first example.

Comment: It is my understanding that "Nothing" in my use case refers to the default value of the datatype, in this case, 0D. 

My sample code attempts to compare the value of D2 against the default value for a decimal.

See my update momentarily

Comment: This example also fails if a value of 0 or 1D is assigned to D2.

Comment: VB's Nothing is not what you might expect. You can assign it to any type instance and is simply the default value for the type when used in an assignment or an equality comparison.

Comment: The OPs example fails even if you replace nothing with 0 or 1D, without using Nothing. The error has nothing to do with Nothing.

Comment: @xpda: we're just responding to this answer's claim that you can't assign Nothing to a decimal. This is not correct - you can.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas, underneath the hood, Nothing is not assigned.  There will always be a value.  Therefore, you can try to assign Nothing, but the value will not truly be nothing/null.  This approach should not be taken because it is not exactly as expected.  E.g., I may have `Dim x As Decimal = 1.0R - 1.0R` which would be 0, but I shouldn't compare that to nothing as it does have a value.  Potentially confusing coding practices should be avoided.

Comment: @ps2goat: I know what you're saying, but you have to realize that 'Nothing' in VB is *not* the same as 'null' in C#/Java/etc.  VB is full of strangeness.

Comment: and that is why I said to stay away from it. Use nullables if you want to test for nothing/null.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as it is.

But usually I would use `IsNothing(D2)` and not `D2 = Nothing`.

Comment: you could also do `D2 Is Nothing`.  But the main point is you should not compare `Nothing` to a value type.

Comment: Basically you are right. I wonder why the compiler allows to set decimal as Nothing.

Comment: It is fine to use the equal sign to compare value types against nothing if your desire is to compare the value type against the default value for that value type.